# Connect to oracle database in ionic2

Tags: java, oracle, cordova, angular, ionic2

Since i am new to ionic2, Can you please give me the solution that how to connect Oracle database using Ionic2.

I have tried using API rest, But in that we are able to connect with MongoDB only.

Am using Visual code source IDE for Developing application, Please help me guys..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to develop **Restful API** where it interacts with the Oracle Database and use that API to fetch and put data (CRUD) from your Ionic2 app.